# How can I rearrange HTML elements from highest to lowest, based on the number thats inside a child of those elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of information that is generated by my webpage.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="num1"><div>1000</div> Some other stuff like more elements </div>
<div class="num1"><div>200</div> Some other stuff like more elements </div>
<div class="num1"><div>400</div> Some other stuff like more elements </div>
<div class="num1"><div>500</div> Some other stuff like more elements </div>
<div class="num1"><div>12000</div> Some other stuff like more elements </div>
```

I want to arrange those div elements in the order from highest to lowest based on the numbers that's inside the elements.

I would want to be able to use jquery or some library to manipulate the divs to be arranged into the order of the numbers from highest to lowest instead of the presented order. `12000 first and 200 last` whilst keeping all the html that is inside the parent DIVS intact.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: So what's stopping you? Have you tried anything at all? What went wrong?

Comment: Thank you I am just trying to get the idea of how to do it before I jump into coding it. I am new to this sort of thing.

Comment: What do you mean _keeping all the html intact_.. how would you be able to sort anything if you don't want to change anything.

Comment: You can see i added more code to above to show where more html elemnts will be. they must all remain intact. Just parent divs must rearrange.

Answer (score 2):

You can just sort them

```
$('.num1').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(b).find('div').eq(0).text() - $(a).find('div').eq(0).text();
}).appendTo( $('.num1').parent() )
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k24G3/2/)

Comment: @adeneo...this will re-order the HTML which is **not** what the OP **apparently** wanted. QUote - "whilst keeping all the html intact." I'd go with this however. +1

Comment: @Paulie_D: I'd imagine that, by 'keeping the html intact', the OP means to say 'without changing the HTML into a new structure for the purpose of the sorting' rather than 'without moving/manipulating the existing HTML.' But you're right, it's ambiguous (and a little confusing).

Comment: Well, you can't keep the HTML the way it is **and** sort it, it's an oxymoron as it's not even remotely possible, you have to move the DIV's to reorder them.

Comment: Or you could move them relatively by css

Comment: @singe31 - Good luck with that, it's going to be a nightmare to figure out.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't be

Comment: Yes I want to just sort the parent Div, in the order of the numbers that is inside the child of these parents. Sorry for confusion.